# How to use R (rvest or XML or RCurl) to scrape data from website like makemytrip

Tags: r, rvest

For instance I want **scrape** flight data for flights operating between Chicago (ORD) and NewDelhi (DEL). I would search for the flights on makemytrip and this is teh URL that gets generated - http://us.makemytrip.com/international/listing/exUs/RT/ORD-DEL-D-22May2016_JFK-DEL-D-25May2016/A-1/E?userID=90281463121653408

When I am trying to read this HTML page using rvest package, this is what I get -

```
htmlpage<-read_html("http://us.makemytrip.com/international/listing/exUs/RT/ORD-DEL-D-22May2016_JFK-DEL-D-25May2016/A-1/E?userID=90281463121653408")
htmlpage
{xml_document}
<html>
[1] <head>\n  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" cont ...
[2] <body onload="done_loading();">\n\n   <div id= ...

myhtml<-html_nodes(htmlpage,".flight_info")
> myhtml
{xml_nodeset (0)}
```

Need help on parsing/scraping this data and understand what is going on wrong here.

Thanks !

Comment: I can only comment that it seems that the html page itself doesn't have the information you're looking for. You might want to check and try `RSelenium`

Comment: @zyurnaidi, Can you share an example of doing it  on us.makemytripcom using RSelenium ? I tried it but wasn't able to provide the search parameters correctly.